# Por que não consigo acessar um campo mas o método consegue?

Tags: c#

Tenho o seguinte código em C#:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    public class BaseClass
    {
        public BaseClass()
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("BaseClass::BaseClass();");
        }
    }
    public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
    {
        public int num;
        public DerivedClass(int x)
        {
            num = x;
            System.Console.WriteLine("DerivedClass::DerivedClass(int x);");
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            BaseClass A = new DerivedClass(20);
            //B.num = 20; Erro
            //Mas se converter para DerivedClass e mostrar resultado do 'num':
            DerivedClass B = (DerivedClass)A;
            System.Console.WriteLine(B.num); //Ele mostra o resultado que modificou no construtor! Ué? Por que isso pode?
            /* Resultado:
             * BaseClass::BaseClass();
             * DerivedClass::DerivedClass(int x);
             * 20
             */
            System.Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

O comentários no código já são auto-explicativos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O problema é que sua referência `A`, do tipo `BaseClass`, pode guardar uma referência para qualquer objeto de `BaseClass`, não somente do `DerivedClass`. Assim, não tem como o compilador saber de antemão qual o tipo real do objeto apontado por `A`, e assim saber que ele possui o tipo `DerivedClass` (e portanto o campo `num`).

(ok, nesse caso, até seria possível se o compilador fosse "inteligente", mas em outros não)

Por exemplo, e se você tivesse:

```
static void teste(BaseClass A) 
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(A.num);
}

static void Main()
{
    teste(new DerivedClass(20)); // tem o campo num
    teste(new BaseClass());      // NÃO TEM o campo num! O que acontece agora?
}
```

Para evitar problemas desse tipo, o compilador só deixa você acessar os campos que ele *tem certeza* que estão lá, daí o erro ao tentar fazer `A.num`.

Formalmente falando, o **tipo estático** de `A` é `BaseClass`, e o **tipo dinâmico** de `A` *naquele momento da execução* é `DerivedClass`. Como C# é uma linguagem estaticamente tipada, o que conta na hora de acessar um campo de um objeto é seu tipo estático. Se ela fosse uma linguagem dinamicamente tipada (tipo JavaScript, Python, Ruby, etc) então esse comando ia funcionar - mas em compensação, provocaria um erro em tempo de execução caso o objeto contido em `A` não tivesse o campo `num`.